# Lemond Frame - what model/year?

Tags: frames

I bought this Lemond frame online. I have an opportunity to get some components for it before I actually receive the frame. Hoping to get more info on the bike (model/year) in the hope of getting some kind of spec sheet. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you can get the serial number off it, you might be able to look it up (http://www.vintage-trek.com/SerialNumbers_draft.htm).

Comment: Best specs are gong to come from a micrometer after you receive the bike.

Answer (score 2):

it could be a 2001, i'm rebuilding a rare one, came with a threaded Icon Air Rail fork, but i used a threaded to non threaded stem converter :D[image: 2001 Chambery]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Chambery.  You can find manuals on http://www.vintage-trek.com

The catalog for 2000 shows the Chambery with a threadless fork.  Yours appears to be threaded so I would guess late 90s.

Comment: I guessing, just guessing, that the fork's not original.